# Problem with UTF-8 encoded XML file containing order and product details and attachment to WooCommerce admin emails

Tags: xml, woocommerce

In a first step I created a custom function in my theme's functions.php file. This function will handle generating the XML file and attaching it to the admin email. In a second step I created another function to generate the XML content based on the order details. Now I have three small problems:

1. the XML is not UTF-8 coded. This means that letters such as ö, ä, ü or é are displayed cryptically.
2. if an order contains several products, the XML only shows one of these products instead of listing them all.
3. an XML is generated, but the suffix .xml is missing.

Here's my function (functions.php placed in my child-theme)

```
/\*\*

* Generate XML file and handle WooCommerce admin emails
  \*/
  function attach_order_details_as_xml_to_admin_email( $attachments, $status, $order ) {
  // Check if the email is being sent to the admin
  if ( $status == 'new_order' && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
  // Generate the XML file content
  $xml_content = generate_order_details_as_xml( $order );

        // Create a temporary file to store the XML content
        $file_path = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'order_details' );
        file_put_contents( $file_path, $xml_content );
      
        // Add the XML file as an attachment to the admin email
        $attachments[] = $file_path;

  }

  return $attachments;
  }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_order_details_as_xml_to_admin_email', 10, 3 );

/\*\*

* Generate the XML content based on the order details
  \*/
  function generate_order_details_as_xml( $order ) {
  // Create a new SimpleXMLElement object
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('\<order\>\</order\>');

  // Add order details to the XML
  $xml-\>addChild('order_number', $order-\>get_order_number());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_date', $order-\>get_date_created()-\>format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
  $xml-\>addChild('order_id', $order-\>get_id());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_key', $order-\>get_order_key());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_company', $order-\>get_billing_company());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_first_name', $order-\>get_billing_first_name());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_last_name', $order-\>get_billing_last_name());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_address_1', $order-\>get_billing_address_1());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_address_2', $order-\>get_billing_address_2());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_postcode', $order-\>get_billing_postcode());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_city', $order-\>get_billing_city());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_state', $order-\>get_billing_state());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_country', $order-\>get_billing_country());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_email', $order-\>get_billing_email());
  $xml-\>addChild('billing_phone', $order-\>get_billing_phone());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_company', $order-\>get_shipping_company());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_first_name', $order-\>get_shipping_first_name());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_last_name', $order-\>get_shipping_last_name());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_address_1', $order-\>get_shipping_address_1());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_address_2', $order-\>get_shipping_address_2());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_postcode', $order-\>get_shipping_postcode());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_city', $order-\>get_shipping_city());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_state', $order-\>get_shipping_state());
  $xml-\>addChild('shipping_country', $order-\>get_shipping_country());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_currency', $order-\>get_currency());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_discount_total', $order-\>get_discount_total());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_subtotal', $order-\>get_subtotal());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_shipping_total', $order-\>get_shipping_total());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_total_fees', $order-\>get_total_fees());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_total', $order-\>get_total());
  $xml-\>addChild('order_payment_method', $order-\>get_payment_method());

  // Add product details
  foreach ( $order-\>get_items() as $item_id =\> $item )
  $product = $item-\>get_product();
  $product_node = $xml-\>addChild('product');
  $product_node-\>addChild('sku', $product-\>get_sku());
  $product_node-\>addChild('name', $product-\>get_name());

  // Convert the SimpleXMLElement object to XML string
  $xml_string = $xml-\>asXML();

  // Convert the string to UTF-8 encoding
  $xml_string = mb_convert_encoding( $xml_string, 'UTF-8' );

  return $xml_string;
  }
```

Any idea to help?

Comment: 1. You need to define xml -  $xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' . $xml_string; 

2. foreach ( $order-\>get_items() as $item_id =\> $item ) is missing { } . 
3. $file_path = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'order_details_') . '.xml'; this should fix it for you